# How to locate the table which doesn't have id or name

Tags: html-table, watir

I need to locate the table,then locate the tr and td, but the table
doesn't have the id and the name, so how to locate the table? I know
should use index,unfortunately it doesn't work.
there are 10 tables in the page, I want
to locate "refesh" in the row of the table,may be  so easy, but I
cannot resolve it... I don't know how to locate the particular table...,no
id, no name, how can I judge which table is what I want to locate.

There is the part of the code:

```
<table cellspacing="0" border="0" style="height:63px; width:">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style=" ">
        <table cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin-top:14px; width:112px; padding-left:15px;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="" rowspan="2"></td>
              <td id="tdrefresh" style="height:28px;" colspan="2">
                <div align="center" onclick="refresh(this,13652,1,1,0,0)" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
                  <div align="center" style="color:#414141;">refresh</div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried browser.cell(:id => "tdrefresh") to locate the cell?

Answer (score 0):

If your true objective is to locate the 'refresh' cell, then Alastair has what sounds like a reasonable answer.  Note however that the event 'wiring' is at the level of the div within the cell, so if your objective is to click on 'refresh' it's really the div that you need to click on

```
browser.cell(:id, "tdrefresh").div(:index, 1).click # note index would be 0 for firewatir
```

Note that if you have input with your developers in terms of test-ability, you might suggest to them that they place the ID at the level of the element which is actually causing action to occur.  For example, the cell above which has the ID does nothing and is merely a passive container, because the 'onclick' event is at the level of the div within that cell.  So it would be a lot more valuable to have the ID on that div, not the cell that contains it.  If that was the case then your code becomes much simpler (and more cross browser compatible).

```
browser.div(id, 'tdrefresh').click
```

Otherwise you are going to need one of two things.

1) something unique, it could be another element, or text, that is within the table. ID since it is supposed to be unique within the page (exclusive of content in frames) is a great choice if it exists, otherwise a combination of other attributes might be needed Some potential examples might be

```
browser.cell(:id, "tdrefresh").parent.parent.parent #parents are row, tbody, table respectively
browser.cell(:text, "refresh").parent.parent.parent  #will need to combine with index of text occurs in more than one cell)
```

or

```
browser.table(:text, /refresh/)  # not likely to work well with nested tables
```

2) some outer container like a div or span, which encapsulates the table, which you can identify by a unique property or combination of properties. (can't suggest anything since you provide nothing above the table tag in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Alastair and Chuck van der Linden
Thank you for your answer,Really helpful.I have tried this code:ie.div(:text=>"refresf",:index=>2).click,
it's ok now.I still verify this problem with your answer.Thank you very much,you give me more ideas to resolve this problem.

Comment: Please click the checkmark icon to 'accept' whichever answer got you the info you need, that's how you 'recognize' the efforts of those who provide answers. 